# I cannot install Chromium or Chrome on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, dependencies, chromium

just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my assembled machine.
Tried to install Chromium via Ubuntu Software or Chrome but installing process stops very soon.
Tried to run in terminal:

```
sudo apt install chromium 

Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done Package chromium is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source However the following packages replace it: chromium-bsu:i386 chromium-bsu E: Package 'chromium' has no installation candidate

sudo apt install chromium-bsu 

Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree       Reading state information... Done You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 chromium-browser-l10n : Depends: chromium-browser (>= 55.0.2883.87-0ubuntu0.16.04.1263) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: chromium-browser (< 55.0.2883.87-0ubuntu0.16.04.1263.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 chromium-bsu : Depends: chromium-bsu-data (>= 0.9.14) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: fonts-uralic but it is not going to be installed or
                         ttf-uralic but it is not installable
                Depends: libalut0 (>= 1.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libglc0 (>= 0.7.1) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libsdl-image1.2 (>= 1.2.10) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Maybe, is there a problem of unmet dependencies..?

Comment: Were there a problem of unmet dependencies, apt would tell you so. Did it?

Comment: Open a terminal and run `sudo apt update` when it finishes run `sudo apt install chromium` and add the out put to your question.

Comment: sassari74@gfl-PC:~$ sudo apt install chromium
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package chromium is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  chromium-bsu:i386 chromium-bsu

E: Package 'chromium' has no installation candidate

Comment: `the following packages replace it: chromium-bsu:i386 chromium-bsu` So for 32bit `sudo apt install chromium-bsu:i386` For 64bit: `sudo apt install chromium-bsu` As for Chrome, the only way to get it is here https://www.google.co.uk/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html#eula I would do you a an answer but the question got closed.

Comment: How to post terminal output? Comment too long...

Comment: Edit it in to your question.

Comment: just done. but I am not able to indent in a code block..

Comment: Open a terminal and run `sudo apt -f install` then try `sudo apt install chromium-browser` my 16.04 says the package should be chromium-browser IDK why it suggested bsu, that is a game.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23767105/

Comment: Run `cd  /var/cache/apt/archives` then `ls` in the output do you find a file a bit like `chromium-browser.deb`?

Comment: sassari74@gfl-PC:~$ cd /var/cache/archives
bash: cd: /var/cache/archives: No such file or directory
sassari74@gfl-PC:~$ ls
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  examples.desktop  Music  Pictures  Public  Templates  Videos

Comment: You made an error in the command, it is `cd /var/cache/apt/archives` you missed the /apt

Comment: excuse me for mistake...  I found 3 of it:  chromium-browser_55.0.2883.87-0ubuntu0.16.04.1263_amd64.deb  
chromium-browser-l10n_55.0.2883.87-0ubuntu0.16.04.1263_all.deb
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_55.0.2883.87-0ubuntu0.16.04.1263_amd64.deb

Comment: OK run `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/chromium*` to remove all them, them run `sudo apt install chromium-browser` and it should install with those broken files gone.

Comment: I will summarize this in an answer, to say thanks, simply accept the answer. Glad this is fixed for you :)

Comment: Thanks from Italy! peace and love. Ubuntu community will grow because of you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the problem was dependencies, these are fixed with

`sudo apt -f install`

The second issue was some left over file from apt's failed attempt to install in /var/cache/apt/archives, to fix this run

`sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/chromium*`

Now Chromium will install

`sudo apt install chromium-browser`

**VOTERS**

Please consider giving [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/519868/75060) some love, it really helped with this question.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Google home page on your browser.There should be a linux download there.download and click on it and it should install automatically.If you cant find it on the home page,search for " Google Chrome Browser download".

Comment: I tried it too. I dowloaded a file .deb; it runs under Ubuntu software but very soon it stops installing.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may occurs when there is a background process is happening

first check any process is happening in background by using `snap changes` in terminal

if there is any process happening stop it by using `sudo snap abort ID number`
here in the place of Id number place the number of  operation which is shown in ID column you want to stop.

this worked for me