# clean, autoclean, and autoremove --- combining them is a good step?

Tags: apt, cleanup

Will it be logical by means of Debian oriented logic to unite the three commands `apt-get clean` and `apt-get autoclean`, and `apt-get autoremove` into one single command that does all of them?

Comment: What "Debian oriented logic" are you referring to?

Comment: Common logic in Debian systems like Debian and Ubuntu. The logic comes out in syntax, commands, terminology, etc.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

This completely depends on what you want to achieve, they are separate for a reason. But lets see what they actually do:

- `apt/apt-get clean` → cleans the packages and install script in `/var/cache/apt/archives/`
- `apt/apt-get autoclean` → cleans obsolete deb-packages, less than `clean`
- `apt/apt-get autoremove` → removes orphaned packages which are not longer needed from the system, but not purges them, use the `--purge` option together with the command for that.

So it is up to you to decide if you want to combine one of the first two with the last one and you can do this like below:

```
sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt clean
```

If thats what you really want to do, but now to code an extra command for it is pretty superfluous to be honest.

Further reading material:

- [manpage for the `apt` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/apt)
- [manpage for the `apt-get` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/apt-get)
- [What is difference between the options “autoclean”, “autoremove” and “clean”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3167/what-is-difference-between-the-options-autoclean-autoremove-and-clean)

Comment: I defined an alias for `sudo bash -c "apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get -y autoremove && apt-get -y clean"` and it serves me well. Caution: `autoremove` removes old kernel images.

Comment: If I understood your answer correctly, you mean to say that `sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get clean` covers everything in `sudo apt-get autoclean`?

Comment: Exactly, autoclean only removes files out out the archives which can no longer be downloaded, clean nukes the archives completely.

Comment: rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*